# Android Image Resizing for different screen devices

Tags: android, image

Here is a list of questions I would like to ask: (I would be grateful if the conversion methods are linked to Photoshop, since it is the Image Editor I use)

Background: I am making an app, that displays images as buttons, and these images are displayed on the whole screen (no room for any other UI). Only one image is displayed at a time (Horizontal ListView) also the app is locked in portrait mode

1. Is there a tutorial out there, that explains how to create ldpi, mdpi, hdpi versions of an image? (Preferably in Photoshop) I have searched around but I seem to get more confused
2. What is the best way to scale the image up or down maintaining the same aspect ratio? For example scaling the image to be displayed the same way on a smartphone and a tablet (I am assuming 9-patch but please clarify)
3. Is it a good practice to start at mdpi and then scale up and down, or start at xhdpi and scale down?
4. When I am creating icons or images in Photoshop to use in the app, what resolution should I start with? (Default I think is 72 pixels/inch)
5. If in future, I would like to add some buttons at the bottom of the screen, how would I go about resizing the image, such that the width of the image covers the screen but the height decreases based on different screen sizes?
6. Is it good practice to stretch the image using XML (I hope not) or make different versions of the same image catering to different screen sizes and place them in the drawable folder?

Please note that although I reinforce the use of Photoshop for conversion, you can direct me to any other method, I just wanted to understand the relation between dp, dpi and px so I could have better control of Images when designing for different apps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Asking multiple questions at once is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Try to narrow your questions down or split them up into multiple questions. Aside from that you can find information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score -1):

i prefer this http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html
which has every tool to customize images.
1 & 2.use nine patch generator
3.create drawable folder then keep your all images in that.the android os will allot the images to corresponding device.I have implemented this in my application which is supporting for all the devices from 2.3 to 4.4
4.it depends on your application. 
5 & 6. don't stretch the image in XML. I too followed that.But it is giving problem with different devices while testing it.
 although make sure that your image should not lost its quality whether it is in device.
hope this helps and i suggest you to do R & D for some time and find your ideas.